# Simcity Delete/Rebuild Great Work?

Tags: simcity-2013

I build an international airport at the great work site I planned for space center. Is it possible to delete the airport so I can rebuild it as space center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked around everywhere, it does not look like demolishing a great work it a feature that is implemented in the current version of SimCity.

This is not surprising, since if that was a feature, griefers could easily retake abandoned cities for the sole purpose of destroying great works/trolling.

Comment: The reason makes perfect sense, but maybe they should enable it for private regions.